# How do I send a cfm file as the body of an e-mail using ColdFusion?

Tags: email, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, model-glue

I have a legacy application where an `email.cfm` file is used with a `cfmail` tag to send e-mail:

```
<cfmail from="abc@123.com" to="def@456.com" subject="New e-mail!">
    // lots of HTML
</cfmail>
```

Now I'd like to update it for **ColdFusion Model Glue 3**. I want to send it using a `mail` object in the **controller**, and include in the body a CFM page:

```
var mail = new mail();
mail.setFrom("abc@123.com");
mail.setTo("def@456.com");
mail.setSubject("New e-mail!");
mail.setBody( ** SOME CFM FILE ** );
mail.send();
```

Does anybody have any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up following Henry's advice in the comments and created a CFML-based CFC:

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cffunction name="SendMail">
        <cfargument name="from"/>
        <cfargument name="to"/>
        <cfargument name="subject"/>

        <cfmail from="#from#" to="#to#" subject="#subject#">
            <!--- HTML for e-mail body here --->
        </cfmail>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Dave Long's suggestion is also good, which is to create components using `<cfcomponent>`, then wrapping the code in `<cfscript>` tags. This gives you the ability to fall back to CFML in case the there is no cfscript equivalent or it's easier to do with CFML:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfscript>
        void function GetData()
        {
            RunDbQuery();
        }
    </cfscript>

    <cffunction name="RunDbQuery">
        <cfquery name="data">
            SELECT * FROM ABC;
        </cfquery>
        <cfreturn data>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can render the content you want to email in a `cfsavecontent` block and then use that in the email, like:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="myemail">
...add some HTML, include another file, whatever...
</cfsavecontent> 
<cfscript>
mail.setBody( myemail );
</cfscript>
```

See http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d57.html

Comment: The `mail` object is in a CFC, not a CFM. This would only work if it's in a CFM.

Comment: @Daniel T. cfsaveconent works in CFC as long as it's not pure script-based like in CF9.  If it is, put it in a CFC that's CFML-based, and call it.

Comment: @DanielT. You can also use the script version of cfsavecontent like `savecontent variable="somevariable" { //do something here }` (see the comment on the linked CF doc page)

Comment: @DanielT. I believe you can also do an include in cfscript like `include "/myemail.cfm";`

Comment: @Henry, I'm using pure script-based CFCs :(, and I can't change it to a CFML one.

Comment: @DanielT. This is wild speculation, but I wonder if `mail.setBody(include "/myemail.cfm");` would work?

Comment: @Daniel T.  Dude, write a new CFML-based CFC, use the solution in the answer, then u can call that new CFML-based CFC inside your CFScript-based CFC.

Comment: Following with @Henry said what I do is almost always start my CFC's with the tag cfcomponent then put all of my functions in cfscript blocks.  That way I can break out into a tag based function when I need to.

Comment: @DaveLong That's a good idea, I should do that from now on. I ended up doing what Henry suggested and created a CFML-based CFC.

Answer (score 1):

Call the CFC assigning it to a variable, like cfset request.emaiBody = cfc.function(). Then just put it in your setBody tag.

Answer (score 1):

OP was convinced to use CFML, but to answer the question as it was initially asked:

```
var mail = new Mail();
mail.setFrom("abc@123.com");
mail.setTo("def@456.com");
mail.setSubject("New e-mail!");
mail.setType("html");
savecontent variable="mailBody" {
  include "email.cfm";
}
mail.setBody(mailBody);
mail.send();
```